# Forçar a implementação de determinado tipo de método abstrato

Tags: python, python-3.x, classes-abstratas, método-abstrato

No `Python` é possível definir `classes abstratas` e `métodos abstratos` de forma ligeiramente simples, por exemplo:

```
class Spam(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def grok(self):
        pass
```

Essa classe não pode ser instanciada pois a mesma possui o método `grok` é definido explicitamente como abstrato, essa classe deve ser extendida e então sobrescrito esse método, segue um exemplo da minha dúvida:

```
class Spam(ABC):

    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def grok():
        pass


class Derived(Spam):

    def grok(self):
        pass
```

Como eu disse antes essa classe deve ser extendida e então sobrescrito o método `grok`, mas vejam que dessa vez o método além de ser abstrato define que também é estático, mas como podem ver nada me obriga ter que definir o mesmo como estático, somente que devo defini-ló.
Minha pergunta é: `Como posso obrigar a implementação do método com seu tipo previamente definido na classe base abstrata?`

Comment: E faz sentido um método estático ser abstrato? Por ser estático ele pertencerá somente a classe, então por que herdá-lo de forma abstrata? Qual o objetivo em fazer isso?

Comment: Vi um vídeo na internet que o cara criou uma abstração base de uma `Pizza` e possuia um método estático chamado `ingredientes`, que retornava os ingredientes da mesma. Esse método deveria ser sobrescrito nas classes bases então ele o tornou `abstrato`, mas como eu disse nada obriga que o mesmo seja implementado sendo `estático`.

Comment: https://www.giacomodebidda.com/factory-method-and-abstract-factory-in-python/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checagens e transformações nos métodos e atributos de uma classe no momento em que são criadas podem ser feitas de três formas diferentes em Python: com o uso de uma metaclasse implementando o método `__new__` ou `__init__`, com o método `__init_subclass__` no corpo de uma classe base, ou usando decoradores de classe.

Uma abordagem via decoradorares exigem que eles sejam usados em cada classe de sua hierarquia - o decorador não é "herdado". `__init_subclass__` pode ser legal em alguns casos, mas vai misturar código na sua classe de Base. Se houver mais de uma classe de base no seu projeto, ambas vão ter que ter o `__init_subclass__` - você teria que fazer um mixin para as classes base - então pode complicar mais. 
O mecanismo que verifica métodos abstratos das ABC usa metaclasses - e pode ser mais natural herdar a metaclasse dos ABC e expandir as checagens feitas.

No caso, a checagem também não é tão trivial - se você quiser usar o marcador padrão do Python `@staticmethod` vai ter que verificar na classe base se o método existe lá - e existe como static, e então levantar uma exceção. (Na documentação até existe um `@abstractstaticmethod` mas é obsoleto - a recomendação é usar os dois decoradores como no seu exemplo mesmo (abstractmethod como o decorador mais interno)

Outro detalhe é que a ABC do Python só da erro de método abstrato não redefinido quando a classe é instanciada, não quando ela é declarada - para métodos estáticos e de classe, essa verificação não adianta, já que podem ser usados sem existir uma instância da classe.

Então, o negócio é realmente escrever uma metaclasse extendendo `abc.ABCMeta` que faça as verificações no `__init__`. Essa verificação tem que incluir verificar todas as superclasses para ver se há algum `__abstractmethod__`, verificar se ele foi ou não overrided na classe final, e verificar se ele era um `staticmethod`: em Python, métodos estáticos são indistinguíveis de função, portanto você tem que recuperar o método a partir do dicionário da classe onde está definido e  verificar com  `isinstance(cls.__dict__["method_name"], staticmethod)`.

Mas é um pouco mais complexo que isso - por que se você tem uma class de base com os métodos abstratos "A", uma subclasse "B" que implementa os métodos abstratos, e uma outra subclasse C que herda de "B", tem que conseguir chegar no dicionárioo da classe  "B"  quando estiver verificando os métodos estáticos na classe C. Isso e possível com o uso do atributo `__qualname__`  nos métodos, mas não é tão trivial.

Como pode ver, há muitos corner cases - vale realmente a pena pensar se você precisa desse mecanismo como está. Ele pode ser feito, mas é um componente de um framework complexo, e que vai na contramão da filosofia da linguagem, em que você deve deixar as coisas serem declaradas, documetnar o que precisa, e dar um erro em tempo de execução se algo não foi bem feito. Claro que é compreensivel a existência de momentos em que isso não é o desejável - tanto que nos últimos anos os mecanismos de indicação de tipagem com  o typing e o mypy evoluiram muito.

Posso escrever essa metaclasse, já que deixo aqui e no gist do GitHub e fica disponível para o futuro - só me confirme que realmente precisa dela, por favor.

Comment: A propósito - vi nos comentários que você está aprendendo sobre OO em Python e achou interessante o método estático para "ingredientes" da Pizza - como você viu na resposta, isso é possível, mas __longe__ de ser o recomendado - métodos estáticos são realmente muito pouco usados em Python.  Mesmo o mecanismo de métodos abstratos é pouco usado, por que as soluções reais feitas na linguagem realmente não precisam disso - é algo muito diferente de uma linguagem estática.

Comment: Um caso de uso pra isso seria somente em um sistema grande, com vários desenvolvedores que vão definir as classes concretas, e que exigisse quase que a criação de um framework intermediário pra minimizar os erros nas implementações - isso depois da arquitetura do sistema todo estar muito bem pensada. Pra seguir exemplos de OOP com classes didáticas de sabores de Pizza, ou animais de estimação, é melhor assumir que esse não é um recurso disponível em Python.

Comment: Eu estou estudando a linguagem a fundo pois acho a mesma espetacular, se pudesse gostaria de ver como ficaria essa implementação que você explicou, mas se for algo que irá prejudicar seu tempo, não precisa, agradeço da mesma forma.